# Is there any problem for loading images more than 200 from resource folder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

My application contains more than 200 images each with size approx. 15 KB. I want to flip these image one by one. Is there will be any time lag for loading images?  Is there any alternate method for doing that?

Anyone please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to flip these images one by one"?

Comment: -1 Going to need more detail. How do you want to display the images?  Are you displaying them in table, a scroll view or do you want to transition to another view for each image? What kind of transform/transition do you want to use? The answer depends on what you are doing, not the size of the images themselves.

Comment: @TechZen don't you think a -1 is a bit too harsh for a new user.

Comment: @Madhup -- It's not directed at the user but the question. Anyone can write a bad question. Giving it a ding not only provides feedback to the author but flags it for everyone else so that they can learn from it or even edit it. Such feedback is central to functioning of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

> My application contains more than 200 images each with size approx. 15 KB. I want to flip these image one by one.

OK.

> Is there will be any time lag for loading images?

Maybe. Try it and see. If there is, run your app under Instruments to see what really caused it.

> Is there any alternate method for doing that?

You haven't proposed a primary method to be alternate to.

The main thing is that, since this is an iPhone app, you're probably not going to need 200 images loaded at once. Consider the Home screen: Those icons are about as small as is practical, and there are only 20 (24 on the iPad) of them on the screen at one time.

Assuming you want to allow scrolling or paging through the list, you'll probably want to keep a pageful up and a pageful down already loaded and flipped and ready to display, to make scrolling/paging faster. That's still only 60–72 images, and you can do half to two-thirds of them *after* displaying the visible 20–36.

Moreover, are the images always flipped? If so, then flip them at build time and copy the flipped images into your app, and do no flips at runtime. Then you're just displaying images.